# Failed to start LSB

Tags: apache2, lamp

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sen 2019-04-01 10:45:24 WIB; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1065 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 01 10:45:24 yui systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui apache2[1065]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui apache2[1065]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: Can't open /
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui apache2[1065]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defin
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, co
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 01 10:45:24 yui systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-c
```

Comment: What changes you made on your machine? Did you try to upgrade or reinstall the Apache web server? 

Check if the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file exists, if not there should be a `/etc/apache2/envvars.dpkg-dist` file. Copy or rename this file to `/etc/apache2/envvars` and try to restart the web server again.